# Java looping to an original statement

Tags: java, loops

I am new to java and need some help with some syntax issues. Basically what I have is a prompt which asks users to enter a password. If they enter a password, then the string password entered is displayed and the password is saved. What I need help with is if the user does not enter any string but just hits the enter button, I want the original prompt to appear. I want it to keep looping till a password is entered. Below is my original code, and what I tried with a for loop. I need some help. Thank you

```
    String prompt = "Enter password ";
    String pw = passwordProvider.getPassword(prompt);


     if (pw != null && pw.length() > 0)
     {
         passwordProvider.status("Password Updated");

       } else {

         System.out.println("here is where I want my original prompt to appear again");
     }

return DRPwCrypt.encryptAES(pw);
```

Code with for loop

```
     String prompt = "Enter password ";
     String pw = passwordProvider.getPassword(prompt);

     if (pw != null && pw.length() > 0)
     {
         passwordProvider.status("Password Updated");
     } else {

         System.out.println("here is where I want my original prompt to appear again");
     }

CODE WITH FOR LOOP

 for (
    String prompt = "Entry " + propertyName + " found in config " + configName +
                    "\nEnter new password : ";) {
String pw = passwordProvider.getPassword(prompt);


if (pw != null && pw.length() > 0)
{
    passwordProvider.status("Updating password");
} else {
    System.out.println("etsting");
}

return DRPwCrypt.encryptAES(pw);
```

}

Comment: Maybe you should consider a `while` loop. `while(pw == null && pw.isEmpty) {}`

Comment: while loop, I would still need to if-else. Is this possible

Comment: You can nest any conditional statement in the while loop. But anyway if the the password is entered the while loop will exit. And the program will continue with the statement after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try using Java's [Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Console console = System.console();
    if(console == null){
        System.out.println("ERROR: Couldn't get Console");
        return;
    }
    boolean passwordUpdated = false;
    while (!passwordUpdated) {

        System.out.print("Enter password :");
        String password = console.readLine();
        // char[] password = console.readPassword() // can be used

        if (password != null && password.length() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Password Updated");
            passwordUpdated = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("WARN: Invalid password, please try again");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** you have to use terminal/command-prompt to run the program, on eclipse System `returns` null console object.

Comment: I cant have a print line for the enter password, because the enter password is a prompt. And I can enter a password which will b saved. I need the original enter password prompt to be displayed, how can i make it loop or return to this prompt if the condition is not met

Comment: It should b sumthin like this       if (password != null && password.length() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Password Updated");
            passwordUpdated = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("WARN: Invalid password, please try again");
      String prompt = "Enter password ";   }
    }
}

Comment: One question, do you want to print "Enter password " or not? If not, then comment out `//System.out.print("Enter password :");` the line. If you want to get it print only in case of invalid password then place the line in else block and comment-out the line with warning message. It would be helpful if you add few lines of expected output to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is *usually* used when you want to iterate a predefined number of times.

In your case, a `while` loop would be a better option:

```
boolean correctPassword = false;
while(!correctPassword) {

     String prompt = "Enter password ";
     String pw = passwordProvider.getPassword(prompt);

     if (pw != null && pw.length() > 0)
     {
         passwordProvider.status("Password Updated");
         correctPassword = true;
     } else {

         System.out.println("Invalid password, please try again");
     }
}
```

`while` loops are used when you want to keep on iterating until a given **condition** is `true` or `false` (as the case may be).

The code above could also be modified to use a `for` loop instead:

```
boolean correctPassword = false;
for(;!correctPassword;) {

     String prompt = "Enter password ";
     String pw = passwordProvider.getPassword(prompt);

     if (pw != null && pw.length() > 0)
     {
         passwordProvider.status("Password Updated");
         correctPassword = true;
     } else {

         System.out.println("Invalid password, please try again");
     }
}
```

The above should create an infinite `for` loop which will keep on iterating until the flag is `true`. As you can see, this might be less readable and/or more confusing than the `while` loop.

EDIT: This code works as epxected for me:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        boolean correctPassword = false;
        while(!correctPassword) {
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             String prompt = "Enter password ";
             String pw = input.nextLine();
             System.out.println(pw.length());

             if (pw != null && pw.length() > 0)
             {
                 System.out.println("Password Updated");
                 correctPassword = true;
             } else {

                 System.out.println("Invalid password, please try again");
             }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: @samujoe: See my edit. I tried to add a complete code sample which does what you are after.

Comment: this only outputs the invalid password prompt, what I want is for the Enter password prompt to be displayed

Comment: can i remove the else and just use the  loop to keep looping until its true ?